# WebMatrix 3 intellisense and publishing

Tags: intellisense, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

Does WebMatrix 3 support intellisense for css libs you add or a customer css file you create? For me this doesn't work. It would be nice to have intellisense when using say twitter bootstrap for instance.

I cannot figure out why when I publish sometimes it selects only the files I've changed but most of the time it seems to publish everything. Why does this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with publish too so I don't recommend using the publish feature in Webmatrix.  I recommend that you copy it directly like this; Right click the app directory in IIS and select "Remove" then just copy and paste the entire project directory from your local machine up to the IIS inetpub/wwroot directory. Then from within IIS7 right click that directory and select "Convert to Application". Works every time.

Comment: It doesn't hurt publishing everything. I just think it is unnecessary. The intellisense issue bothers me more.